# My SSD keeps getting full. What files are there anyway?

Tags: ssd

I do not install new software. I do not download new movies. It starts of at 90GB and then now it's 110GB. Slowly but surely the space is taken.

I don't know what takes it.

How do I know?

Comment: @terdon I don't think so. While his question is similar I believe it wouldn't have some of the same answers. With windows defragging is a good idea and can free up decent amounts of usable space. But as you may know defragging isn't a good idea on a SSD.

Comment: @Griffin there is no mention of defrag in the question I linked to, what there is is a nice long list of utilities that can show you what is eating up your disk space. It is one of many many such questions on this site.

Comment: There may be no mention and I did not state there was one. Defrag is still an answer even if it's not mentioned.

Comment: @Griffin: As far as I'm aware defragmentation does not "free up" any space at all. Can you provide a reputable source to prove the contrary?
Either way, defragmentation is not recommended on an SSD.

Comment: @oKtosiTe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFWMhaLXet4 A youtube video I watch a while back. I found it again.

Comment: @oKtosiTe Also here http://helpdesk.its.uiowa.edu/windows/instructions/defrag.htm it states Usually the less gaps of free space between the contiguous segments the better, but as long as the fragmented files are put together into contiguous segments, it will help your computer's performance.   When these free spaces become to small Windows will not register it as space last I check. This causes slight loses in space which on large full drives adds up. Fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several programs in Windows claim some temporary space, e.g. Google Chrome for some cache, cookies etc. A tool to quickly clean this kind of data is CCleaner. It is freely available. If after running CCleaner you have your diskspace back, you know it was taken up by temporary files.